# Scale background image width to the size of the div

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, background-image

I have a div with an unknown width. I want it to have a large background image.

How do I set the background image width to be as the width of the div itself? (the height of the div is known).

Comment: @AhsN I tried exactly what la1ch3 wrote in the answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Background size will work, but the aspect ratio of the image will be changed. 500px below is the known height.

```
.myDiv {
    background-image: url(image.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 500px;
}
```

More info on background-size [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fbackground-size), it's not supported on <= IE8.

Or alternatively you could absolutely position an image relative to the container, but background-size is better.

```
img.cover {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute:
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I looked for

Answer (score 2):

```
.myDiv {
    background-image: url(image.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain; (you could also use cover here)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but than the height of the background image is changing, and I want to avoid this

Comment: @Tal is you want to maintain aspect ration, then either the height or the width is likely to shrink. Or do you want the height to stay the same but have the image stretch to fit the width?

Comment: I want that the height will stay the same, only the width of the background-imaghe should change

Comment: @Tal I'm a little confused. So, you want the background image height to stay (which I'm assuming is shorter than your div height) but you want the width to be flexible?

Comment: @Tal using `contain` should maintain your height while allowing the width stretch.

Answer (score 1):

Use background image in the div and [background-size](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) css propierty.

Example:

```
#im {
background-image: url("path/to/img");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}
```

You can also set the image width to 100% to fill your content div. In order to use height 100% you need specify your div height.

Answer (score 0):

The following CSS attributes will make the background width fit to a dynamic container:

```
.myDiv {
    background-size: 100%; /* fit width to container */
    background-repeat: no-repeat; /* do not repeat background */
    height: 200px; /* height is known */
}
```

See an [example on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m38efqz3/)